# Por alguma razão essa aplicação não concatena "endereço da pasta + valor de célula"

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

boa tarde! Venho buscar opiniões.

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em vba que puxa informações da planilha para preencher cabeçalho, corpo e anexar arquivos.

Meu intuito é que que ele **concatene o "endereço da pasta + nome da empresa" para puxar o arquivo correspondente àquela empresa**. O "endereço da pasta" está declarado na planilha.

Já tentei de algumas formas, são elas:

1. uso de "thisnotebook.path & empresa"
2. substitui cells.value por range

O arquivo já se encontra na mesma pasta do projeto.

Até agora a aplicação está assim:

```
Sub envio_qualificaçao()

Dim anexo, empresa, para, cc, data, assunto

cc = Range("b29").Value
linha = 3

Do
    empresa = Range("f" & linha).Value
    assunto = Range("B3").Value & empresa 
    para = Range("i" & linha).Value
    anexo_PCC = Range("b35").Value

    
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("outlook.application")
Set Email = objOutlook.createitem(0)

With Email
    .SendUsingAccount = "myemail"
    .To = para
    .cc = cc
    .Subject = assunto
    .body = Cells(32, 2).Value
    .attachments.Add (anexo_PCC & Cells(linha, 6).Value & ".png")
    .display
    
End With

linha = linha + 1
Loop While Range("F" & linha).Value <> 

    
End Sub
```

**O erro informado é um problema na localização do arquivo, me pede para revisar o caminho declarado**. Ao testar com o endereço completo, ele roda normalmente (porém infelizmente isso não é o ideal, pois teria que inserir o endereço de todos os anexos manualmente).
Aqui está o print: [image: print do erro com informação: Não é possível localizar este arquivo. Verifique se o caminho e o nome do arquivo estão corretos]
Qualquer ajuda é muito bem-vinda.

Agradeço!

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Dois detalhes, Karolyna:

Comment: 1) Estou sem acesso a um computador agora, mas acho que não deveria haver esse parêntese externo em ```attachments.Add (anexo_PCC & Cells(linha, 6).Value & ".png")```. Tente deixar ```attachments.Add anexo_PCC & Cells(linha, 6).Value & ".png"``` e diga se funcionou.

Comment: 2) Você pode avaliar a expressão ```anexo_PCC & Cells(linha, 6).Value & ".png"``` e dizer qual foi o resultado?

Comment: Por fim, você pode colar o erro?

Comment: @CésarRodriguez Cesar, de antemão obrigada pela resposta! Fiz o teste e infelizmente o erro persiste, a aplicação não encontra o caminho. Adicionei o print do erro à publicação.

Comment: Ótimo! Este erro significa que o VBA tentou encontrar o arquivo, mas não conseguiu. É importante dizer também em que linha ocorreu o erro. Por favor, conforme se foi na linha ```.attachments.Add [etc]```.

Comment: Se for nessa linha mesmo, vamos descobrir qual é a pasta em que ele está procurando. Por favor: (1) clique em "Depurar" na janela de erro; (2) no modo de depuração vá ao painel de visualização instantânea (é um painel em branco onde podemos digitar, geralmente abaixo do painel com o código; se não estiver aparecendo, use o atalho Control + G); (3) no painel de visualização imediata, em qualquer linha em branco, digite ```?anexo_PCC & Cells(linha, 6).Value & ".png"``` e dê Enter.  Diga o que apareceu na linha abaixo, no próprio painel.

Comment: Esse será o caminho completo do arquivo que o Excel está procurando e não encontrando. A partir daí, descobriremos se o problema é no nome do arquivo ou se faltou uma subpasta.

Comment: Em tempo, aproveite e diga também o nome do arquivo que deseja anexar, com o caminho completo, para comparação.

Comment: Só por clareza: no painel de visualização imediata, quando no modo de depuração, você sempre pode digitar uma expressão precedida por interrogação, e ele avalia aquela expressão.